# Declarative relationship sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Trying to create relationship between tables in data models.

```
Class masters(Base):
    __tablename__='master'
    id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    code = Column(String(128),nullable=False)
Class Payments(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'payments'

    code = Column(String(128), ForeignKey('master.code'),nullable=False, unique=True)
    source_id = Column(ForeignKey('master.id'), nullable=False)

    source = relationship('masters', primaryjoin='Payments.source_id == master.id')
    code1 = relationship('masters')
```

Only the relationship between source and id has been established(while viewing relationsal schema, exported this to db visualizer).
How can I define correct relationship so that both relationships reflects in the schema?

Trying to determine the solution quickly and easily as I have not much context to sqlalchemy.

Comment: What kind of relationship are you trying to create?

Comment: many-to-many as two different fields are related to two different fields

Comment: For clarification, why do you want/need to do this? If `master.id` is a primary key and `payments.source_id` is a non nullable foreign key, that means every record in payments must have a parent in master. That being the case, it seems mistaken to try to store `code` twice (once in each table) rather than joining them whenever needed. I'd like to understand this.

Comment: at query level, we sometimes don't need to join from the primary key, and also doesnt need it taht often. Plus downtown increases if we filter by joining from the primary key. BAsically, other teams want to join from the "code" field as well. How to inculcate it is my simple question.